# Why my favicon from favicon generator can't be loaded?

Tags: html, favicon

My web icon (favicon) doesn't appear

I already use manual link code for favicon nor just put my favicon.ico in root directory
Then I use Real Favicon Generator, but it doesn't change my favicon

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#1d983e">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Kalpataru">
<meta name="application-name" content="Kalpataru">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2c2c2c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

These files already in the root directory in /public_html/. The code must be referring to these paths correctly. But still doesn't appear. When I open it manually to .ico .png files, they don't appear in my web but .jpg appears.

Comment: What does your server error log say?

Comment: Your code does not reference any `favicon.ico` file,

Comment: @Martin Since this file is (supposed to be) in the root directory of the site, this is okay. Browsers look for `/favicon.ico` by convention. And I agree with your question about the logs, there is something weird with the file extensions.

Comment: @Martin browser look for favicon.ico in root directory by convention like philippe_b said